# Obtain the mysql database handler using the database name

Tags: mysql, c, database

We have two applications that will create different databases and inserts information into it. The data is inserted into the databases using the connection handler that we obtain at the time of database creation.

Suppose database "X" is created by application 1. Is the database connection handler of database "X" available in application 2? Do we have any **API in C** for that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [MySQL C API](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/c-api.html).

Yes, mysql stored databases according to the name, which is shared between all applications.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How we can get the connection handler of the database?

Comment: [mysql_real_connect](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-real-connect.html) connects to a server and a default database. You can change default databsae after joining, rarely required, using [USE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/use.html) as a sql statement.